# Writing actionListner to display form input on console upon confirmation

Tags: java, user-interface

I am currently constructing a GUI which allows me to add new cruises to the system. I want to write an actionListner which once the user clicks on "ok" then the form input will be displayed as output on the console.

I currently have the following draft to complete this task:

```
    ok = new JButton("Add Cruise");
            ok.setToolTipText("To add the Cruise to the system");
            ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                int selected = typeList2.getSelectedIndex();
                String tText = typeList2[selected];
                Boolean addtheCruise = false;
                addtheCruise = fleet.addCruise(); 

                fleet.printCruise();

                if (addtheCruise)
                { 
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                }
                else
                {   // Report error, and allow form to be re-used
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                    "That Cruise already exists!", "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }                       
            }
        });        
        buttonPanel.add(ok);
```

Here is the rest of the code to the Form input frame:

```
 contentPane2 = new JPanel (new GridLayout(18, 1)); //row, col 
            nameInput = new JLabel ("Input Cruise Name:");
            nameInput.setForeground(normalText);
            contentPane2.add(nameInput);
            Frame2.add(contentPane2);

            Cruisename = new JTextField("",10);
            contentPane2.add(Cruisename);
            Frame2.add(contentPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            Frame2.setVisible(true);

            confirmPanel = new JPanel ();
            confirmPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            confirmPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.PINK));

            addItinerary = new JButton("Add Itinerary");
            confirmPanel.add(Add);
            confirmPanel.add(addItinerary );
            Frame2.add(confirmPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            Frame2.setVisible(true);

                contentPane2.add(Cruisename);
                Frame2.add(contentPane2);

            // add spacing between comboboxes
            contentPane2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));

            contentPane2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

           //Label for start and end location jcombobox
            CruiseMessage = new JLabel ("Enter Start and End Location of new Cruise:");
            CruiseMessage.setForeground(normalText);
            contentPane2.add(CruiseMessage);
            Frame2.add(contentPane2);               

            /**
             * creating start location JComboBox
             */

            startL = new JComboBox();
            final JComboBox typeList2;
            final String[] typeStrings2 = {
                "Select Start Location", "Tobermory","Oban", "Isle of Mull", "Isle of Harris",
                "Lewis and Harris", "Stornoway", "Skye", "Portree"};

            startL = new JComboBox(typeStrings2);

            contentPane2.add(startL);
            Frame2.add(contentPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            Frame2.setVisible(true);

            // add spacing between comboboxes
            contentPane2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));

            /**
             * creating end location JComboBox
             */

            endL = new JComboBox();
            final JComboBox typeList3;
            final String[] typeStrings3 = {
                "Select End Location", "Tobermory","Oban", "Isle of Mull", "Isle of Harris",
                "Lewis and Harris", "Stornoway", "Skye", "Portree"};

            endL = new JComboBox(typeStrings3);

            contentPane2.add(endL);

            Frame2.add(contentPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            Frame2.setVisible(true);

            // add spacing between comboboxes
            contentPane2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));

              //Label for select ship jcombobox
            selectShipM = new JLabel ("Select Ship to assign Cruise:");
            selectShipM.setForeground(normalText);
            contentPane2.add(selectShipM);
            Frame2.add(contentPane2);   

            /**
             * creating select ship JCombobox
             * select ship to assign cruise
             */

             selectShip = new JComboBox();
            final JComboBox typeList4;
            final String[] typeStrings4 = {
                "Select Ship", "Dalton Princess", "Stafford Princess" };

            selectShip = new JComboBox(typeStrings4);

            contentPane2.add(selectShip);
            Frame2.add(contentPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            Frame2.setVisible(true);
```

I need all form inputs from the code above to be displayed on the console upon completion.

**Summary:**
1. I have two ships in one fleet
2. To add new cruise, all fields (Name, start date, end date, ship) must be selected.

**The Problem:**
1. I keep coming up with errors when creating " fleet = new Fleet();" in my constructor. Even though I have declared it in my class.
2. In the draft code below, line 5 states "typeList2", however, I have two JComboBox's - two different type Strings for both drop down menu's (Shown in the rest of the code). How do I input both typeLists to the output rather than just one?

Thank you.